# How to read a generic rest xml file into a java object?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, xsd

I have an XML rest endpoint that I am converting to an object using an xsd. The structure of the xml changes over time which means I have re-write my xsd file to match the structure of the newly updated xml. Is there a generic way to be able to write the structure of the xml into a java class ? , even if I don't know the structure of the xml until I read the content of the xml.

A possible solution is to use a high level xml data structure which contains many fields of which some may or may not be used. But this seems a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most generic model that represents XML document is DOM that can be created from indeed any XML document. Using DOM you can create generic application that does not depend on schema of XML documents you are working with. However going "down" from JAXB (or similar XML-to-objects mapping) to DOM requires a lot of additional work. The question is do you really need this and what are you going to do with the data.

If for example you are creating generic XML editor or viewer this approach looks reasonable because editor does not "know" anything about data it works with.

If however you are creating application that "knows" the data this method is probably not applicable. In this case you anyway have to know what to do with specific XML tags, so you anyway need model that depends on XML document. In this case you probably have to just be up-to-date with changes of XML schema and create appropriate POJOs according to version of XML schema.